# Login to Facebook for Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, go, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

How can I organize login with Facebook in my Angular 2 app (with creation of a user account and authorization on my backend server)?

At this moment I can get `authorization_code` from Facebook and then get `access_token` with my backend app.

Now I try to create an Angular 2 app with a login page and an `AuthService` that sends a request to Facebook and handles the redirected answer with `authorization_code` and then sends this code to my backend server in order to receive `access_token`, create a new user if necessary and return a JWT to my Angular 2 app.

How can I handle Facebook's response (callback) with `authorization_code` in my Angular 2 app in order to send it to my backend (in order to receive JWT)?

Comment: You need a route Facebook can call back to that handles the URL parameters appropriately. I recently implemented this for OAuth via GitHub: https://github.com/textbook/prioritise-me/blob/d38a371784270146ad5f148bbb0573a2bce53def/web/src/app/auth/github/github.component.ts#L22. For OAuth to work you send the user away to the provider, then the provider needs to know where to send them back to.

Comment: Facebook has a guide to implementing OAuth with examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/. You need to have a page at the `redirect_uri` that can handle the returned information.

Comment: Thanks! One problem is... how can I use # in redirect_uri? or it is not possible?

Comment: @AndreyK. Could you paste a sample code how to get `authorization_code` from Facebook in Angular?